# WPF: Binding large collections to GridControl

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, data-binding

I've just started on my first WPF project and I ran into a problem this morning. 
There is this large collection of locations (50.000) I want to bind to a *GridControl*.

```
    public void BindData()
    {
        //disabling the control seemed to shorten the UI lock.
        gcLocations.IsEnabled = false; 

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            gcLocations.SetPropertyThreadSafe("ItemsSource", OceanData.OceanPorts.Values);
        });

        gcLocations.IsEnabled = true; 
    }

    public static void SetPropertyThreadSafe(this Control control, string propertyName, object value)
    {
        Type type = control.GetType();
        var prop = type.GetProperty(propertyName);

        if(prop == null)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("No property has been found in '{0}' with the name '{1}'", control, propertyName));
        }

        object[] param = new object[] { propertyName, prop.PropertyType, value };
        if(prop.PropertyType != typeof(object) && prop.PropertyType != value.GetType())
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Property types doesn't match - property '{0}' (type:{1}) and value '{2}'(type:)", param));         
        }

        if(control.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            prop.SetValue(control, value);
        }
        else
        {
            control.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                prop.SetValue(control, value);
            }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, null);
        }
    }
```

Because I want my applications to remain responsive to the user I've been looking for an alternative method to bind this data in one go. So i came to this idea.. Is it possible to pause the binding operation when a lock occurs  in the interface so that the interface can update itself? I'm pretty new to programming so excuse my ignorance :)

thanks ~~

Comment: As far as I can see, your code is adding 50'000+ controls to a GridControl ... that's going to takes some time, and it's going to happen on the UI thread! Do all 50'000 controls need to be visible at the same time? Or do you scroll to view them? This problem is crying out for some kind of virtualisation of your data ...

Comment: try using the `ListView` for this sort of display and `GridView` to define custom view for your control. When you use `ListView` you can use the benefits of `VirtualisingStackPanel` which provides the  Virtualisation, hence the name :-). Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! @olitee no not at all. But in some cases the user needs search for a location and edit a property. I use a Devexpress gridcontrol which has a very good a filtering data. unfortunately a listview doesn't have this feature. i'd have to create a custom control for this so i'd rather keep using the gridcontrol.

Comment: The GridControl from DevExpress should default to virtualizing your data out of the box. Have you already tried simply databinding the values collection to your ItemsSource? What *is* the underlying collection? Is it already in memory?

Comment: @olitee, I'm currently binding the value a Directory<T> which is already in the memory. What you do mean by "Default to virtualizing data out of the box"?

Comment: @Nieksa From what I read here, the GridControl supports virtualizing: [link](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q482410) "GridControl for WPF supports the vertical and horizontal virtualization mechanisms. The first one is always enabled, and it is impossible to disable it."

Comment: i did not know it functions this way, thanks for the info.

Comment: No worries - I've added some useful links to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DevExpress GridControl supports data virtualization, whereby only the controls/items that are visible on screen are constructed and added to the visual tree. Furthermore, those visible controls are usually recycled as you scroll down your list, saving the costs of rebuilding them.

If you're not familiar with virtualization, consider a simple list view example: You may bind a data source containing, say, 10,000 items to it, but only 20 items might be visible to the user at any one time. The virtualization mechanism ensures that only the list items that are visible are created. Without this feature, the list box would have to create 10,000 WPF list items (which in turn may contain several controls or UI elements), and hold those in memory AND add them to the visual tree, even though they are not visible. WPF controls can only be added to the visual tree on the UI thread, which is what will be causing your code to hang.

It appears that the DevExpress GridControl supports virtualization out of the box, but it may be enhanced by use of their own DevExpress Datasource classes. [Check out this documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument10803) ... it may be you need to make use of the [LinqServerModeDataSource](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/clsDevExpressXpfCoreServerModeLinqServerModeDataSourcetopic) or [LinqInstantFeedbackDataSource](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/clsDevExpressXpfCoreServerModeLinqInstantFeedbackDataSourcetopic) classes to give you the performance you're looking for.

Comment: thanks for your comment @olitee. I found this project the perfect solution for my problem :) https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3382